# Multiple Domains, multiple Store View and redirect

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I have 2 different domains (www.mysite.com and www.mysite.it) associated at 2 different Store View (code=en and code=it). After set from backend my Magento 1.9.0.1 to works with different domains, I set my .htaccess to redirect to the right store view and the right associated domain:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en

SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
```

This works well except for one thing:

if I type *mysite.com/myproduct-name* or *mysite.it/myproduct-name* **without www** it brings me to the respective homepage (www.mysite.com and www.mysite.it).

**How can set it so that redirect me to the www version of the content (e.g. www.mysite.com/myproduct-name)?**

---

Edit

Ok, **I think this is the problem**, this is hot .htaccess part:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.it/ [R=301,L]

# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mysite.com$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]


SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host www\.mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
SetEnvIf Host ^mysite\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
```

- In this situation redirect of product is resolved but I can access only to www.mysite.it
- If I uncomment row 3 and 4 I'm not able to access both domains anymore.
- If I remove **!** from both conditions I can access to both domains but redirect to www product page doesn't work anymore

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the trick:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and you need to set in `System-->Configuration-->Web-->Auto-redirect to Base URL-->NO`

Thank you all

Comment: This worked great for me. I use an always-on HTTPS connection so changing the http%1 in the last line to just https solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

A simple rewrite will address that.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried but still redirect on the homepage.

Comment: Rewrite rules are processed before the Magento redirect. If you are experiencing a redirect, then its either your browser cache, or the rewrite rule hasn't been implemented correctly.

Comment: I clear all browser cache, open it in a different browser in anonymous window. Furthermore, _RewriteEngine On_ and the above rewrite directive are write before Mage SetEnvIf (although they are processed before).

Comment: I also tried as mentioned in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317177/magento-redirects-to-base-url-using-302-how-do-i-get-it-to-use-301]

Comment: Checking site with this tool I received a warning of "potential duplicated content" for / and /index.php. In fact and more precisely address mysite.com/myproduct-name take me to /index.php

Comment: If I set _Use Web Server Rewrites_ to _NO_ in Magento backend (System->Configuration->Web->Search Engine Optimization) it works like a charm but my product address now is **www.mysite.com/index.php/myproduct-name**.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the MAGE_RUN_CODE value should correspond with the store *view* code!

**[Edit]**
If you can edit your vhost config, you could just use `SetEnv` for each vhost https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

Comment: That's what OP stated in the question.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just could not delete my post. Sorry for that!