# Multi store with different domains, cookie store is causing problem

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, cookie, multidomain

Please note that it's not another "how to setup multistore". I've read other questions and it seems that my problem is not described.

Following are not answering my question:

- [set default page to Particular store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146955/set-default-page-to-particular-store-view)
- [How to create Multiple Store with different domain in Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/how-to-create-multiple-store-with-different-domain-in-magento)
- [Multiple Domains, multiple Store View and redirect](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42716/multiple-domains-multiple-store-view-and-redirect)
- [How to set up second store in multi-domain configuration?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8359/how-to-set-up-second-store-in-multi-domain-configuration)
- [Optimise URL when changing Store and language switcher to maintain SEO standards](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127422/optimise-url-when-changing-store-and-language-switcher-to-maintain-seo-standards)

I think this question describes the same issue but the answer is kind of workaround [Separate store view which reverts back to the default store view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140480/separate-store-view-which-reverts-back-to-the-default-store-view)

I want to have different store views with different domains. I've created all store views like below:

START OF STANDARD SETUP, NOTHING FANCY, YOU CAN SKIP READING THIS

```
base
---- store
-------- polish (default)
-------- german
-------- ...
```

And I've set `web_[un]secure_base_url` for each and put them in `index.php`.

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'polishstore.pl':
        $mageRunCode = 'polish';
        $mageRunType = 'store';
        break;
    case 'germanstore.de':
        $mageRunCode = 'german';
        $mageRunType = 'store';
        break;
    // ...
    default:
        $mageRunCode = 'polish';
        $mageRunType = 'store';
}
```

Note that I've also set in configuration:

- Add Store Code to Urls: No
- Auto-redirect to Base URL: No

END OF STANDARD SETUP, NOTHING FANCY

**Description of the problem**

It works pretty good, but I faced some issues:

1. When going to http://polishstore.pl/?___store=german it sets cookie `store=german` and loads german store. From now http://polishstore.pl/ loads incorrectly german store.
2. When going to http://germanstore.de/?___store=polish it doesn't set cookie `store` because this store view is default. But it loads polish store. Consecutive visits without `___store` loads correctly german store.

   ```
   // app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:562
   if ($store->getWebsite()->getDefaultStore()->getId() == $store->getId()) {
       $this->getCookie()->delete(Mage_Core_Model_Store::COOKIE_NAME);
   }
   ```
3. In such situation it is not possible to access polish store anymore, because of cookie. Helps only deleting that cookie or accessing http://polishstore.pl/?___store=polish.

**Alternative scenarios that I've tried**

Please note that setting **Auto-redirect to Base URL** to **Yes** doesn't help, because then it works as described below:

1. http://polishstore.pl/?___store=german -> http://germanstore.de cookie `store=german`
2. http://germanstore.de/?___store=polish -> http://polishstore.pl no cookie -> http://germanstore.de (because of cookie from step 1)

I would like to make it that domain name tells which store view to load, no matter if cookie is set. It may be that the parameter `___store` overrides it but it's not required.

**Possible soultions**

1. Delete cookie `store` or don't set it at all. Deleting cookie in index.php is not working correctly, it works on the second pageload.
2. Ignore `___store` parameter. Use only domain names to determine which store to load.

In both situations it is needed to modify `Mage_Core_Model_App` (copy it to local). Maybe you have better idea. Please comment or post your answer.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212804/magento-2-multiple-websites-or-stores-in-local/212806#212806

Comment: Hi @mkutyba, did you ever find a solution for ignoring the `store` cookie?