# Magento 2: Multiple websites and stores on apache or nginx server

Tags: magento2, multistore, language, multi-website

I know this question may have been previously asked but I followed many reference links, but I cannot do this thing so please help me achieve it.
base URL = http://127.0.0.1/magento22/

1) Create a site in Magento with 4 languages

- Deutschland (German)
- Francais (French)
- Nederland (Dutch)
- Switzerland (Swiss)

2) Change code in index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}
$params = $_SERVER;
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
switch ($actual_link) 
{
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/deutschland/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'deutschland'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        break; 
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/france/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'france'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
         echo "11";
        break; 
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/nederland/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'nederland'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        break; 
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/switzerland/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'switzerland'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        break; 
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'base'; 
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
        break;     
    default: 
        $params = $_SERVER;
        break; 

}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Do you have assign website URL in admin as per website?

Comment: yes i have assign url as per index.php. @SureshChikani

Comment: Above code working or not as per website?

Comment: if i run http://127.0.0.1/magento22/deutschland/ this url than google code of this website change, but 404 page display and also if i click any of the link it redirect to base link http://127.0.0.1/magento22/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Created multi website in magento, Steps to create a multistore in admin panel is same as like in magento1.x. Don't forget to change the base url and secure url for new website/store. Once made changes in admin panel follow the below steps,

1) Create a new folder in magento root and copy the `index.php` and `.htaccess` files from magento root to new folder.

2) Edit the `index.php` which is in new folder

**Replace:**

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**With:**

```
 $params = $_SERVER;

 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'newstore'; //Webite code as same in admin panel

 $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';

 $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

 /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */

 $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');

 $bootstrap->run($app);
```

And also update bootstrap.php include path as below,

**Replace:**

```
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
```

**With:**

```
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
```

3) Create a simlinks inside the new folder

```
 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app 

 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib 

 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/pub/ pub 

 ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var
```

Refer [this](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts.html)

Please clear the `var/generation,var/cache and pub/static` files and do the static content deployment.

[image]

[image]

Final Step:-store->configuration->general->web->select store view and add base URL for Each Store

Comment: 3) Create a simlinks inside the new folder, I have to copy my  app, lib, pub and var inside new folder?

Comment: https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts.html

Comment: I can not understand simlinks where i have to do this think.

Comment: it's simple first you only 2 website create and check.

Comment: check update image

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me, but when i click any of the url, for example for about:- http://127.0.0.1/magento22/deutschland/about but in redirect to http://127.0.0.1/magento22/about

Comment: i will do but i have problem which was post above

Comment: which problem are face

Comment: when i click any of the url, for example for about:- 127.0.0.1/magento22/deutschland/about but in redirect to 127.0.0.1/magento22/about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72907/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-kushal).

Comment: creating symlinks and copy folders this is the most stupidest idea - magento already have store code, just add to server config and add proper rewrite.

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala What if my website's Access Point is Pub instead of Root. Can you help me, please?

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala I am using Nginx Server and in that Magento Root Access comes from PUB Folder so i cannot set multiwebsite from Default Root Folder

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala Can you pls help me for magemnto 2.3 multi website https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/256694/57334

Answer (score 1):

**If The Server Is NGINX then Follow Below Steps.**

Here is the scenario. We have two different websites, and each website has two different store views as follows:

**Website 1**

- Website 1 (E-commerce)
- Website 1 (Venda Assistida)

**Website 2**

- Website 2 (E-commerce)
- Website 2 (Venda Assistida)

In my solution, we are going to change some configuration in Magento Admin. Then we are going to create some sub-folders, and finally we are going to modify nginx.conf.

First of all, we need to make some configuration change in the Magento Admin. Go to Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web. We need to change Base URLs for each store view.

For Default Config
Please provide the following configuration for default config.

[image]

**For Website 1 (E-commerce) and Website 1 (Venda Assistida)**

Please provide the following configuration for all Website 1 store views.

[image]

**For Website 2 (E-commerce) and Website 2 (Venda Assistida)**

Please provide the following configuration for all Website 2 store views.

[image]

Secondly, we need to create website1 and website2 folders in the /pub directory. In the final, you should have the following folders:

- MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/website1
- MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/website2

Copy the pub/index.php file into these directories. Then we will make some changes in `MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/website1/index`.php and `MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/website2/index.php.`

Content of `MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/website1/index.php`
I have only changed 3 lines:

1st Line: `require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';`

2nd Line: `$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website1';`

3rd Line: `$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';`

```
<?php
/**
 * Public alias for the application entry point
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website1';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

For the final touch, we need to modify nginx.conf in your MAGENTO_ROOT directory. Please put the following configuration into your nginx.conf.

```
location /website1 {
    root /website1;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /website1/index.php last;
        break;
    }
}

location /website2 {
    root /website2;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /website2/index.php last;
        break;
    }
}
```

After all this configurations and modifications, you will be able to use websites as sub-folders.

Comment: Hello Jaimin, can i get docs for Create magento 2.3 Multi Store in Wamp Localhost

Comment: Where should i create a subfolder for symbolic links, Root folder or under the pub folder? @Jaimin, Teja Bhagavan Kollepara

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Example - run a particular store or website:
 * --------------------------------------------
 * require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
 * $params = $_SERVER;
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'website2';
 * $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
 * $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
 * \/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app *\/
 * $app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
 * $bootstrap->run($app);
 * --------------------------------------------
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];

//$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
{
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/deutschland/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'deutschland';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/france/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'france';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        echo "11";
        break;
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/nederland/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'nederland';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;
    case 'http://127.0.0.1/magento22/switzerland/':
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'switzerland';
        $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website';
        break;
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: I want to use the same media, pub, static view.

Comment: Please check with this code.

Comment: Please check it with my updated code.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'Bootstrap' not found in /var/www/html/magento22/index.php:36

Comment: with this code $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], i can get 127.0.0.1

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: @SureshChikani Where should i create a subfolder for symbolic links, Root folder or under the pub folder? may i know nginx configuration my single-store nginx setup => https://justpaste.it/7bkdv how to should be update for multi website?