# Create Multi Website in magento 2

Tags: multistore, magento2.2.3, multi-website

I have created multiple website from magento admin, also as per the magento devdocs I've followed the instructions for multi website sub-folder architecture.

However its throwing me below error. also I found that my default magento website throwing me the same  error after processed with multi-website scenario. [click here for error info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3eJX.png)

Also I've followed this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94855/create-multi-website-stores-in-magento-2?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212804/magento-2-multiple-websites-or-stores-in-local/212806#212806

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a Websites and it's relevant Store and StoreView from Admin > Stores > All Stores
2. Go to Stores > Configuration, Select website which you have created. Then Go to Web and change both **Base URLs & Base URLs (Secure)**

   For example : 
   e.g. Base URL: xyz.com (Main website url keep as it is)
   Base Link URL: {{unsecure_base_url}}ch/

   Here, **ch** is a sub directory folder which needs to create under your magento root folder
3. Create a sub directory folder, then copy index.php & .htaccess from root
4. Open index.php replace everything with the code bellow:

   ```
   require realpath(__DIR__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
   $params = $_SERVER;
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'ch_website'; 
   $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
   $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
   $app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
   $bootstrap->run($app);
   ```

   **ch_website** is a website code.

Comment: Thanks bro. It helped me. i made small mistakes in url. Thank you so much

Comment: Thanks, It helped me a lot.

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara I am getting issue, could you pls help me?